# select XElements with xmlns

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces, xelement

How do you select an element with xmlns specified? I need to select Include/Fragment element. I've tried adding  http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi before element names, but that doesn't work. In XmlDocument there was NamespaceManager functionality, but I don't see same stuff in XDocument. So how do I select an element with xmlns?

```
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment/>
</Include>
```

I've tried:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> Fragments = d.Element("Include").Elements("Fragment");
```

and

```
const string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi/";
IEnumerable<XElement> Fragments = d.Element(xmlns+"Include").Elements(xmlns+"Fragment");
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is a Linq-to-xml problem (hence the retag). Can you include what you've tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: @Conrad Frix I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make your `xmlns` variable a `XNamespace` (instead of just a string):

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";

IEnumerable<XElement> Fragments = doc.Element(xmlns + "Include").Elements(xmlns + "Fragment");
```

then it should work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement yourfile = XElement.Load("yourfile.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
    from el in yourfile.Elements("Include")
    where (string)el.Attribute("XElement") !=null
    select el;
```

I tried to implement the code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675197.aspx
It also converts it to a list. Hope that helps